# Codeigniter HMVC error calling function in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404, hmvc

I have a problem in CI when i try to call a method in the same controller but it ends up in giving

> "Object Not Found 404 Error"

I call a module "Login" which is the `default controller`, its `index` runs fine but when i try to send data from a form it starts showing the `404` error.

All the `routes` and the `config` files are fine

This is the code in the View I call the controller method from:

> Application > Modules > Login > Views > Login.php

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url('login/login/validate_user/'); ?>" method="post">
    <div class="login-form" id="login_view">
        <p>LOGIN IN.</p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="USERNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>

            <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="manage_login('login_view', 'fp_view');"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 1. For url creation use site_url() instead base_url()
2. Remove action attribute from form and proccess form data on same action

Comment: check the form action URL from the HTML of rendered page. It might give you a clue where the data is being sent

Comment: are u remove index.php from url in htaccess ??? if not then it is cause of this error

Comment: it goes to the controller method i want, my problem is the page gives me a 404 error

Comment: i added index.php to .htaccess but still gives the same error

Comment: use echo base_url('index.php/login/login/validate_user/'); for test or why are u adding login 2 times is login class contain login method?

Comment: login two times beacuse login is the name of the module and the controller as well

Comment: echo base_url is returning the correct link

Comment: have a look here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hmvc-an-introduction-and-application--net-11850

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form without base_url();

```
<?php 
$attributes = array('class'=>'m-t','role'=>'form','method'=>'post');
$this->load->helper('form');
echo form_open('login/validate_user',$attributes);
?>
    <div class="login-form" id="login_view">
        <p>LOGIN IN.</p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="USERNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>

            <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="manage_login('login_view', 'fp_view');"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: my problem is not submiting the form, my problem is that which ever controller function i try to access it shows a "Object Not found 404 Error"